# When opening any excel file in system, excel file running in background created by windows form (vb.net) also appears

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

My windows form opens an excel file (let's say Test.xlsx) in background to read and write content. Test.xlsx file stays open in the background as long as the form is open. Excel visibility has been set to False in the code. But, when I open other excel files in the system, Test.xlsx is also appearing. Not sure why this is happening. Check code in below hyperlink.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xtb2.png)

Comment: I think we will need to see some code on how you open the Excel file before attempting to magically guess how you application works

Comment: Please provide some related code or more details here, so that it will help others analzye your problem and make a test.

Comment: Code snapshot added. Please click hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want 'Test.xlsx' file to appear, you need to close it first.

```
xlWb.Close(0)
xlApp.Quit()
```

Besides, close excel in form_closing event is not a good choice, because if the form does not close properly, the resource will not be released, then you will see multiple 'Excel.exe' in your task manager.

Release it in time.

```
    xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(link)
    '...
    xlWb.Close(0)
    xlApp.Quit()
```